# C++ passing a nested unordered_map by reference and manipulating it

Tags: c++, unordered-map, nested-map

I have 2 classes (`firstClass` and `secondClass`) of which `firstClass` is a friend of `secondClass`, and has a private nested `std::unordered_map`, which I want to access it in a function of `secondClass`.

So basically the code is like this:

```
class secondClass;
typedef unordered_map STable<unsigned, unordered_map<unsigned, double> > NESTED_MAP;

class firstClass {
    friend class secondClass;

    void myfunc1(secondClass* sc) {
        sc->myfunc2(&STable);
    }

private:
    NESTED_MAP STable;
};

class secondClass {
public:
    void myfunc2(NESTED_MAP* st) {
        //Here I want to insert some elements in STable.
        //Something like:
        st[1][2] = 0.5;
    }
};

int main() {
    firstClass  fco;
    secondClass sco;
    fco.myfunc1(&sco);
    return 0;
}
```

The point is that if instead of the nested map, I use a simple `std::unordered_map`, I can easily modify it (add new elements, or change the values of some keys). But, in the nested map I can not do anything.

I know that it should be trivial, but I don't know how to solve it.
Any idea?

Comment: Reference in the title, pointer in the code.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot it. I knew that I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing by reference, you're passing a pointer. This is a version using reference:

```
void myfunc2(NESTED_MAP &st)
{
    st[1][2] = 0.5; // valid, st dereferenced implicitly
}
```

And call it without address-of operator:

```
sc->myfunc2(STable);
```

If you really want to pass a pointer, it needs explicit dereferencing:

```
void myfunc2(NESTED_MAP *st)
{
    (*st)[1][2] = 0.5;

    // or, if you like:
    st->operator[](1)[2] = 0.5;
}
```

In the code you posted, you `firstClass` has only private members (forgot `public:` ?).